# What is the simplest way to compare truthiness in this specific way?

Tags: javascript, truthiness

Given the following instructions I have created a function that achieves the requirements. I feel my function is a bit too complex, though it does what it's supposed to. The difficult part for myself was avoiding the equality operators. The only way I could think to solve this is with a bit of math and a comparison operator. How can I simplify this function and save some editing time?
Thanks in advance.

> Write a function `onlyOne` that accepts three arguments of any type.
>
> `onlyOne` should return true only if exactly one of the three arguments are
>   truthy. Otherwise, it should return false.
>
> Do not use the equality operators (`==` and `===`) in your solution.

My function:

```
function onlyOne(input1, input2, input3) {
    output = false;
    let truthy = 0;
    let falsey = 0;

    if (!!input1) {
        truthy++;
    } else {
        falsey++;
    }

    if (!!input2) {
        truthy++;
    } else {
        falsey++;
    }

    if (!!input3) {
        truthy++;
    } else {
        falsey++;
    }

    if (falsey > truthy) {
        output = true;
    }
    if (falsey > 2) {
        output = false;
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: This might be better suited to ask on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you, Lex. I will ask there now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would call `Boolean` on each argument and `reduce` into a number, and then check the truthyness of that number minus one:

```js
const onlyOne = (...args) => {
  const numTruthy = args.reduce((a, arg) => a + Boolean(arg), 0);
  return !Boolean(numTruthy - 1);
};
console.log(onlyOne(0, 0, 0));
console.log(onlyOne(0, 0, 1));
console.log(onlyOne(0, 1, 1));
console.log(onlyOne(1, 1, 1));
```

Or, for a more concise but less understandable version, you can integrate the `1` into the initial value provided to `reduce`:

```js
const onlyOne = (...args) => !args.reduce((a, arg) => a + Boolean(arg), -1);

console.log(onlyOne(0, 0, 0));
console.log(onlyOne(0, 0, 1));
console.log(onlyOne(0, 1, 1));
console.log(onlyOne(1, 1, 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` and `count` as below.

In `filterCount` function first parameter will decide whether you want count of `truthy` or `falsy`.

```js
const filterCount = (bool, ...args) => args.filter(i => i == bool).length;

console.log("truthy = " + filterCount(true, 1, 0, 0));
console.log("falsy = " + filterCount(false, 1, 0, 0));
console.log("truthy = " + filterCount(true, 1, 0, 1));
console.log("falsy = " + filterCount(false, 1, 0, 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

```
let onlyOne = (a, b, c) => !(!!a + !!b + !!c - 1);
```

`!!` coerces the values into booleans. `+` coerces the booleans into numbers, where `true` becomes `1` and `false` becomes `0`. We sum up the numbers and now we can have any one of these potential totals: 0, 1, 2, or 3. We only care about a total of 1 which we can subtract 1 from to get 0 and then negate it (which coerces it back into a boolean) which makes it `true`.